# Adding domain resource records to the SoftLayer domain intemittently canonicalizes the entry

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating DNS domain entry via, Network->DNS->Forward zones portal, sometimes via API also.

POST to https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord.json

with below data

{"parameters":[{"data":"fe20:0000:0000:0000:0202:13ff:fe1e:8329","domainId":2063407,"host":"somehost.com","responsiblePerson":"user@softlayer.com","ttl":1000,"type":"aaaa"}]}

With the above POST sometimes the entry for the above AAAA record is fe20::202:13ff:fe1e:8329

Similarly for some cname entries I get DOT appended to the name. So if I gave test.com it becomes test.com.

Answer (score 0):

this may be an issue with the API I recomend you not to use the SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord method to create the records and use the same methods that the portal uses to create them in that way you will avoid issues with the API.

The methods that the API uses to create the records are these:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createAaaaRecord
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createARecord
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createCnameRecord
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createMxRecord
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createNsRecord
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createPtrRecord
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/createSpfRecord

You need to pick the correct method according the record type that you want to create.

I hope this helps you

Regards

Comment: Of course I can change to these, but if it is a known issue in the API shouldn't they fix it? Thanks for your response though, I will try these. The interesting part of the problem is that it is intermittent.

Comment: I do not know if it is a known issue, if you are still getting the same issue with the methods that the control portal is using I recomend you to open a ticket in control portal and report the issue in order they fix it.